# dell e6400 lcd blanks out during boot

Tags: laptop, boot

lcd blanks out after initial "windows starting" screen comes on. External monitor works fine and laptop completes the boot normally and runs everything fine using external monitor. Running Windows 7 32 bit release. All drivers and bios are up to date. (Update) With the external monitor attached, if I repeatedly press F4 during the boot, the screen will come back on but in a reduced (narrower) size window. When I pull the external monitor plug the screen goes to full size. It may then work for days or screw up again the next day. This "work around" has worked each time I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its totally black? Does it appear to be slightly lit? If you hold a flashlight at it can you vaguely see anything being displayed on the screen?

Newer laptops have LEDs not LCDs, which do not have power inverters. If your laptop is older, say 5 years+ there is a chance your LCD inverter or LCD itself has gone bad.

Replacing either is very delicate work even for experienced techs. I would recommend you get a professional to take a lookie see.